# difference between these two sentences

Tags: grammar

I was wondering how are these two sentences different. Also, if one is wrong please suggest the correction.

1. I have revised the designs to incorporate the changes you **have** suggested.
2. I have revised the designs to incorporate the changes you suggested.

Comment: I think the second one's better, because the perfect tense clarifies that the suggestions happened before the revisions.  If, however, the revisions were not the result of the suggestions, then "I have already revised the designs to incorporate the changes you have suggested." might be better.

Comment: If the suggestions were _not all made at the same time_, neither phrasing is totally clear. Try "I have revised the design(s) to incorporate the changes you suggested on {date} [and {date}]."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the simple past ("you suggested") implies that the writer has in mind some specific occasion when the suggestions were made, such as at a meeting. Using the present perfect ("you have suggested") implies that the writer is not thinking of any specific time in the past when the suggestions were made but simply has the suggestions in mind currently, as he writes that sentence. He may be responding immediately after the suggestions were made.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable. It really depends on the situation. The first is more formal, the second would be more likely to happen if you were saying the sentence. If writing it, a compromise on "you've" might be better.

Comment: How is the first sentence more formal?

Comment: I think in general sentences without contractions are more formal than sentences with, and sentences with contractions more formal than sentences missing words.

Answer (score 1):

They are pretty interchangeable, but the second is the one to use, because it is more mellifluous.  That second present perfect comes across pretty tedious, and it really isn't necessary.

You could also say *to incorporate your suggested changes.*